# How to import Vue object inside .js file to html

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am using Vue.js for some data binding and data filtering.
I have created a Vue object inside a .js file and I want to export it and then import it from my html.

[My object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cIZEY.png)

I have tried to export with `export default { testObject };` and then import it in html like (my file is inside a folder named js/ ).

```
<script type="module" src="js/testFile.js">

    var testObject = require('./js/testFile');

</script>
```

This doesn't seem to work.

Is there a way which this can be done?

Comment: I recommend you use Vue CLI - it works by default.

Comment: I'd like to see your testFile.js (or at least a minimal version of it)

Answer (score -1):

The only way you can use features of modern Javascript (`export default` and ES modules) is to use build tools.

Fortunately Vue already has this, and it also has single file components.

https://cli.vuejs.org/

Comment: Most browsers support modules out of the box: https://caniuse.com/#search=modules You only need build tools to target IE and legacy versions of browsers.

Comment: I'm aware of that but given OP never said that he DIDN'T wan't to support IE, it is safe to assume that OP would still want that. Thanks for the downvote though.

Comment: Then edit your question so it is at least factually correct. It is most certainly not the "only way" to use modern javascript features. That is probably why you were downvoted.

Answer (score -1):

You are exporting using ES6 module syntax and trying to import using commonjs modules.

You want to import something like this:

```html
<script type="module">
import TestObject from '/js/testFile'
</script>
```

See the [import documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) for more information.

Comment: I have also tried that but it does't work. When i try to log my object in the console it doesn't show anything

Comment: You don't need the `src="js/testFile.js"` attribute in the script tag either. It could be that which is causing the issue as I don't believe you can have the `src` attribute and content at the same time.

Comment: @memeister I've just realised you might have tried to log the object directly from the console which won't work as the console doesn't have access to variables inside modules unless you explicitly add them to the global scope. If you add the `console.log` inside the module script tag after importing the object then it should work.